# Google Drive API - Changes: list. Getting the original ID of a deleted file

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs

When trying to detect deleted objects using the Changes: list feed, I noticed that the `id` value is incorrect making it impossible for me to detect which file was deleted. Example:

Make new testfile : This is a test file

```
public 'title' => string 'This is a test' (length=14)
public 'id' => string '1wUFHe3DfU1mJnyqlIgAYSvMrIy8F91-7rZyAPFsyVpg' (length=44)
```

Now when I delete this file the first entry for a deleted change is:

```
public 'deleted' => boolean true
protected 'fileType' => string 'Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile' (length=30)
protected 'fileDataType' => string '' (length=0)
public 'fileId' => string '1_8Cvirw71AY0HQoaNwSMP3TlcIFAhpZikVfOrXFZCLo'        (length=44)
public 'id' => string '3612' (length=4)
public 'kind' => string 'drive#change' (length=12)
public 'modificationDate' => string '2013-12-23T10:55:45.340Z' (length=24)
public 'selfLink' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/3612' (length=48)
  protected 'modelData' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'processed' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

None of the identifiers (`fileId` and `id`) equal the `id` from the file 'This is a test file'. I read in the API documentation that the results are from the bottom up, but non of the deleted changes contain my original file id.

How would I know which file was deleted?

EDIT: I've created a video showing my problems, steps

- I create a new file (just before the video started)
- I show it's ID in the Changes: list
- I delete this file
- I create another file
- I show the file ID in the Changes: list
- The Changes: list shows my first file ID and right after that the second created file ID. It doesn't show to delete file event

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh2ARFdxWGk

Sorry for the poor quality, I used a bad screen recording tool

Comment: Note: the change list you show is from 2013. This is not the changelog you are looking for.

Comment: Could you tell me where the newer changelog is? I got this list using the API

Comment: KRR answered that below, you'll need to page through the changelogs - it's a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the [Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/) instead of Changes. I just tested with Apps Activity API and both trash and emptyTrash show as events. [The API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/appsactivity/v1/appsactivity.activities.list?drive.ancestorId=root&groupingStrategy=none&source=drive.google.com&userId=me&_h=5&) gives you an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I can see all the changes I'm looking for. Too bad the Changes list isn't working (for me?)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that the entries in the changes feed are ordered in ascending chronological order. That is, the oldest changes show up first. So check the last enries in the response.

You can also try this in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list). Get the first set of list and for getting the latest changes you can either get the `nextPageToken` from the response or the `largestChangeId` from the last change in the list  and get the next set of changes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, sadly as I posted non of the changes match my original ID. This is when using the API explorer and when using the PHP library

Comment: The delete may not appear in the change list instantaneously. Check again later.

Comment: Hey, using the `startChangeId` I do get the latest changes and I see the creation of files, but when deleting I still don't get the ID in my changes list. I tried changing the maxresult to the max to get ALL the changes, but still my deleted ID didn't show up. Isn't there an easier way to get the latest changes, now I have to store the latest key somewhere.

Comment: With the following GET: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes?includeDeleted=true&includeSubscribed=true&maxResults=999&startChangeId=26449&fields=items(deleted%2CfileId)%2ClargestChangeId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` `26449` being the changeId from my file creation, I still get no deleted events. But my activity explorer in drives does indicate that the file has been removed

Comment: When creating a document, then deleting that document and then creating a document I only see the first and third event. I don't see any deleted events...

Comment: Have you tried using the nextPageToken from the first result set in API explorer?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, also tried putting the maxResult to a maximum. As you can see in the video I posted I am able to see recent events, just not deleted events. Could this be an issue because I have multiple accounts logged in?