# Is there any specific for google drive file_id

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to know max-length and possible character type for google drive file_id, to save file_id in DATABASE.

I could not find file_id's specific in the reference https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

Comment: Based on my testing using google docs and spreadsheet, fileID has a total length of 44 and consist of numbers, letters and special characters. You can also see in this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937315/google-drive-api-changes-list-getting-the-original-id-of-a-deleted-file), the OP also counted the file ID as 44.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rebot! In my google drive, special chars contains only `-` and `_`. Have you ever seen the other speciar chars?

Comment: It seems the character length is 33 for drive folders and 44 for files.